# Add parameters to a build to be edited a "Queue" time

Tags: tfs, build-automation, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I have made several custom process parameters.  They are for versioning purposes (ie IsMajorBuild, IsMinorBuild, etc.)

When I right click on my build and select Edit Build Definition, then select Process I see all of my custom parameters listed there.

But when I queue a new build and click on "Parameters" I only see some of the "Basic" and "Advanced" items.

Is there a way to get at least some of my custom parameters into that list?  It would be nice to be able to indicate a minor build with out having to:

1. Open the Build Definition
2. Edit the custom parameters and save
3. Queue the build
4. Open the Build Definition
5. Put the parameters back and save

If could get them in the queue parameters, I could just change it while queuing the build.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a parameter to the metadata, there is a "View this parameter when:" combo box.

That lets you choose if when you want to see it.

Just as an FYI, the xml tag is called [BrowsableWhen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2009/12/23/tfs-2010-custom-process-parameters-part-2-metadata.aspx)